# Fish-eye warping about mouse position - fragment shader

Tags: glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, ogl

I'm trying to create a fish-eye effect but only in a small radius around the mouse position. I've been able to modify [this code](https://www.geeks3d.com/20140213/glsl-shader-library-fish-eye-and-dome-and-barrel-distortion-post-processing-filters/) to work about the mouse position ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-water-397br?file=/index.html:3380-4437)) but I can't figure out where the zooming is coming from. I'm expecting the output to warp the image similarly to this (ignore the color inversion for the sake of this question):

[image: desired fish-eye effect]

Relevant code:

```
// Check if within given radius of the mouse
vec2 diff = myUV - u_mouse - 0.5;
float distance = dot(diff, diff); // square of distance, saves a square-root

// Add fish-eye 
if(distance <= u_radius_squared) {
  vec2 xy = 2.0 * (myUV - u_mouse) - 1.0;
  float d = length(xy * maxFactor);
  float z = sqrt(1.0 - d * d);
  float r = atan(d, z) / PI;
  float phi = atan(xy.y, xy.x);
    
  myUV.x = d * r * cos(phi) + 0.5 + u_mouse.x;
  myUV.y = d * r * sin(phi) + 0.5 + u_mouse.y;
}

vec3 tex = texture2D(tMap, myUV).rgb;

gl_FragColor.rgb = tex;
```

This is my first shader, so other improvements besides fixing this issue are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the vector from the current fragment to the mouse and the length of the vector:

```c
vec2 diff = myUV - u_mouse;
float distance = length(diff);
```

The new texture coordinate is the sum of the mouse position and the scaled direction vector:

```
myUV = u_mouse + normalize(diff) * u_radius * f(distance/u_radius);
```

For instance:

```c
uniform float u_radius;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;

void main()
{
    vec2 diff = myUV - u_mouse;
    float distance = length(diff);

    if (distance <= u_radius)
    {
        float scale = (1.0 - cos(distance/u_radius * PI * 0.5));
        myUV = u_mouse + normalize(diff) * u_radius * scale;
    }

    vec3 tex = texture2D(tMap, myUV).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(tex, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Rabbid! Though I had to subtract 0.5 from the diff and add 0.5 to the myUV inside the if statement to get it positioned properly.